# Will be the travel less than before COVID 19?

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, transit-visas

As the case of COVID 19 the international border is closed. After it gets normal will people to travel like they were doing before or it will be reduced?

Comment: Welocome to Travel SE. Unfortunately you are asking us to speculate on something which does not really fit into the scope of this board. The amount of travel will depend in part on the economy, which will depend on *when* and *how* things get back to normal. Analysts are talking about V-shaped, U-shaped and L-shaped recoveries. We answer questions about things like visa and airport transfers.

Comment: Have you tried asking your crystal ball?